# How to turn a random graph into a matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, matrix

I have constructed a random graph with Mathematica using the `RandomGraph` command. Now I would like to convert this graph to a matrix, but I don't know how. The command `//MatrixForm` just shows the same with "//MatrixForm" so that doesn't help to much either.

Comment: Tried `AdjacencyMatrix` ? Also posting your code would be really useful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Philip! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time [you will be able to do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Comment: `MatrixForm` is meant for pretty printing things that are already matrices.

Comment: @Nasser, on the other hand, `Normal[]` might not always be a good idea, if the matrix has particularly large dimensions...

Answer (score 10):

Please see [Graphs and Matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphsAndMatrices.html) guide page for related functionality. Below is usage summary.

This is creates a random graph with 9 vertexes and edge 0.4 probability. `SeedRandom` allows to reproduce the graph across multiple evaluations.

```
SeedRandom[3]; g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[9, 0.4], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .3]
```

[image]

And these are matrix types that you can get from your graph:

```
Labeled[MatrixForm[#[g]], #] & /@ {AdjacencyMatrix, IncidenceMatrix, KirchhoffMatrix}
```

[image]

There is also `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` for graphs with weighted edges.